# How to match first string with column and print Match?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is

```
data = {
        'company_name' : ['auckland suppliers', 'Octagone', 'SodaBottel','Shimla Mirch'],
        'year' : [2000, 2001, 2003, 2004],
        'desc' : [' auckland has some good reviews','Octagone','we shall update you','we have varities of shimla mirch'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

i tried this code

```
df['CompanyMatch'] = df ['company_name'] == df ['desc']
```

I want to print "Match" if the first word of company_name column matches with the desc column.I am confused as in where to put index [0] so that it prints this way:

```
> company_name         desc                                 CompanyMatch
> auckland suppliers   auckland has some good reviews       Match
> Octagone             Octagone                             Match
> SodaBottel           we shall update you                  NA
> Shimla Mirch         we have varities of shimla mirch     Match
```

Comment: It's a little mysterious what "match" means in this context--for example the "auckland" line matches but why?  Is it enough that they share a single word in common?  What are the rules?

Comment: @JohnZwinck it's a rule that is instructed while validating company name and its description when one has limited data.

Comment: Sorry, I edit answer. Then first row not match, right?

Comment: it has to "match" as auckland is the word that is present in the desc column

Comment: @jezrael your previous answer was correct

Comment: Unfortunately not :( because it return match for unmatched values.

Comment: @jezrael I guess I'll have to bother you again, as the understanding is a bit different here, i wish to print match if and only if the first word(and not the whole string) of a column matches with the other column. Example "auckland suppliers" should print match as the first word auckland is present in the other column.

Comment: @A.Info - So is possible extract only first word from `company_name` and then check it? No problem if last comapre is between `Shimla` only?

Comment: @jezrael exactly only its only the first word match I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok, give me a sec.

Comment: @A.Info - Check edited answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for check one column value in another by `in`, `axis=1` is for processing by rows:

```
import numpy as np

m = df.apply(lambda x: x['company_name'].lower() in x['desc'].lower(), axis=1)
df['CompanyMatch'] = np.where(m, 'Match', np.nan)
print (df)
         company_name                              desc  year CompanyMatch
0  auckland suppliers    auckland has some good reviews  2000          nan
1            Octagone                          Octagone  2001        Match
2          SodaBottel               we shall update you  2003          nan
3        Shimla Mirch  we have varities of shimla mirch  2004        Match
```

EDIT:

For compare first word only:

```
m = df.apply(lambda x: x['company_name'].split()[0].lower() in x['desc'].lower(), axis=1)
df['CompanyMatch'] = np.where(m, 'Match', np.nan)
print (df)
         company_name                              desc  year CompanyMatch
0  auckland suppliers    auckland has some good reviews  2000        Match
1            Octagone                          Octagone  2001        Match
2          SodaBottel               we shall update you  2003          nan
3        Shimla Mirch  we have varities of shimla mirch  2004        Match
```

Comment: Perfect! @jezrael